# NativeAd callback onAdImpression not run react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, admob, google-ads-api

I am using Admob (react-native-admob-native-ads) package with my react-native(android) app. I have a problem with NativeAd, **onAdImpression** callback on NatveAd is not called even after the ad is loaded and display on screen. But when i open my app from app-tray onAdImpression called correctly.

Here is my code for NativeAd

`<NativeAd ref={nativeAdViewRef} adUnitID={NATIVE_AD_ID} onAdLoaded={()=>console.log('Ad Loaded successfully')} onAdImpression={()=>console.log 'impression count'}/>`

Here **Ad Loaded successfully** printed in concole but **impression count** not until i open my app from app-tray